# cgo how to represent go types in c?

Tags: go, cgo

*when export go func to c, the interface type port to GoInterface, and int to GoInt. How to port my c funcs to go with these types?*

a.h

```
void *SomeFunc(GoInterface arg);
```

a.c

```
void *SomeFunc(GoInterface arg) {
}
```

a.go

```
package main

// #include "a.h"
import "C"

type A struct {
}

func main() {
    var a = new(A)
}
```

*when I go build:*

```
cc errors for preamble:
In file included from ./a.go:3:0:
a.h:1:16: error: unknown type name 'GoInterface'
 void *SomeFunc(GoInterface arg)
```

*Is there a header file for go like jni.h for java, So I can include there types.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Go doesn't have any way to export types as "C readable". Further, you **cannot** reference a Go struct from within C, and it is not safe to try and finagle a C struct to "look like" a Go struct since you have no control over memory layout.

The "right" way to do this is to create a type in a C file and add it as a field in the Go struct:

```
// from C
typedef struct x {
    // fields
} x;


// From Go, include your .h file that defines this type.
type X struct {
   c C.x
}
```

Then operate on your type that way, and pass `C.x` into all your C functions instead of `x`.

There are a couple other ways, (for instance, converting between them any time you want to use it as one or the other), but this one is the best in a vague general sense.

Edit: a FEW Go types can be represented in C, for instance, `int64` will be defined in code that's compiled via cgo, but for the most part what I said holds.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to say that these types are defined, but they're passthrough-only. The only thing you can meaningfully/safely do with them is pass them back into Go code.

Comment: Yes, that's the point! Since the only thing I can do is pass them back. From where I could get them. Because, go cannot pass these types to me. I have no method to build one in C. this confuse me. Thanks for your patient, Jsor.

Comment: That's what I said in my answer, you want to use the C struct from C, and then for all the code you call from C, you want to return a C.x instead of an X. You could even make a function like `func AsCType(x *X) *C.x` and call `AsCType(MyFunctionThatReturnsX())`.

Comment: Yes, I did what you said in my code. I #defined void * GoObject, and use it in my code for go struct types, it works fine. Maybe _cgo_export.h is just not a complete design till now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Those types are used internally by cgo.  They aren't documented and they aren't intended for use by the program using cgo.